# Random Number Generator Objective-C iOS8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, random, ios8, nsmutablearray

My app has a mutable array in a data model (used to pass data between views) which allows users to add the names of 'housemates' as strings to a table view controller. I want to later generate a random housemate in another view controller i.e. when a button is pressed I want the label underneath it to display the randomly selected housemate. I wondered if I could assign each housemate a number and, when a random number is generated, use an if/else statement to say something like:

if randomNumber == 0 {

self.label.text = self.housemate0.text;
}

But I'm unsure how to count all the housemates in the mutable array and then assign/tag them with a number to later be generated and how the actual code for generating the number/updating the label would work. Could anyone help me please? Many thanks.

Comment: The housemates already _have_ numbers. That's what an array _is_.

Comment: "I'm unsure how to count all the housemates in the mutable array" Howzabout saying `theMutableArray.count`?

Answer (score 0):

A NSArray, or NSMutableArray is index based, so every entry has an unique index number to access it like myarray.objectAtIndex:1

And counting your array will be done by myarray.count

Is that what you expected with your question?!? :-)